# Get separate Order's tax totals amounts with tax class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

I'm making personal a PDF invoice plugin for woocommerce.

Some of our products has tax with Reduced rate (%8) or Standart rate (%18). For example, Product A = Reduced rate (%8), Product B = Standart rate (%18). I can get total of tax amount easily but I want to print with ***sperate tax total amounts with tax class***.

How to get total Reduced rate tax amount of an order? Also Standart rate.

How can I *echo* them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Tax class is not registered anywhere in the order data… It's registered in each product and optionally for shipping.

You can simply use the dedicated `WC_Abstract_Order` method [`get_tax_totals()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_tax_totals) *(as Woocommerce uses for separated tax rows)* and you will have the tax label percentage that is set in each tax line settings.

The Rate code `$rate_code` is made up of COUNTRY-STATE-NAME-Priority. 
 For example: `GB-VAT-1` or `US-AL-TAX-1`.

The code to display separated tax rows:

```
// Get the WC_Order instance Object from the Order ID (if needed)
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Output the tax rows in a table
echo '<table>';
foreach ( $order->get_tax_totals() as $rate_code => $tax ) {
    $tax_rate_id  = $tax->rate_id;
    $tax_label    = $tax->label;
    $tax_amount   = $tax->amount;
    $tax_f_amount = $tax->formatted_amount;
    $compound     = $tax->is_compound;
    echo '<tr><td>' . $tax_label  . ': </td><td>' . $tax_f_amount . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

> If you want to display something like `Reduced rate (%8)` or `Standart rate (%18)`, you will have **to customize the "Tax name" in the Tax settings** for each tax line in each Tax rate (But it will be displayed everywhere and not only in your custom PDF plugin).

Additionally, the Tax class is just for settings purpose and for admin view.

Comment: Thanks for reply @LoicTheAztec I have tried your sample code but didnt get any result unfortunately. Should i change anythink on the code? Thanks again.

Comment: @OnurK. This is simply not possible as it really work, because it's what woocommerce uses… How have you tested this code?… where have you included it? where is your own plugin code?