# WooCommerce: Get order export with tax lines

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

I want to export all my orders with the tax lines separated by tax rate.

For example: An order could have the tax rates 7% and 19%. If the order has products with both tax rates, I only get one combined tax amount.

Let's say the order has two products for 100€ each. There would be the following taxes:

- 100€ at reduced rate: **7€**
- 100€ at default rate: **19€**
- taxes combined: **26€**

I'm using the following code (excerpt) to export order data:

```
$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data 
$order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('d.m.Y'); // Example for oder creation date
```

After getting the data, I need to store them in an array:

```
$custom_data = array(
    'custom_order_date_created'     => $custom_order_date_created,
)
```

What I need is a fixed column (like the `$order_date_created` above) for every tax rate.

Like:

- Column 1: tax rate - **7%**
- Column 2: tax amount - **7€**
- Column 3: tax rate - **19%**
- Column 4: tax amount - **19€**

If there is no amount for a tax rate the column could be empty.

I know that there is an order property called `tax_lines`. But it's an array and I don't know how to use it. The property `tax_lines` has some own [tax lines properties](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-tax-lines-properties).

Does anyone has a clue how to get these values from an order?

**EDIT:** I found a snippet in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52958085/1788961):

```
foreach ( $order->get_tax_totals() as $rate_code => $tax ) {
            $tax_rate_id  = $tax->rate_id;
            $tax_label    = $tax->label;
            $tax_amount   = $tax->amount;
            $tax_f_amount = $tax->formatted_amount;
            $compound     = $tax->is_compound;
            echo '<tr><td>' . $tax_label  . ': </td><td>' . $tax_f_amount . '</td></tr>';
        }
```

It looks right, but I'm not sure how to use it with my code example and store it in my array.

**EDIT 2:** After some more digging I found the `WC_Order_Item_Tax` [object](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item-Tax.html) which has the order tax items in it.
So I tried to use that data but it is an huge object and I'm not sure how to select the data and show it in the right column.

It looks like this (there is a lot more). And I need to select the tax by the `rate_id` for example:

```
[4543] => WC_Order_Item_Tax Object
        (
            [extra_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [rate_code] => 
                    [rate_id] => 0
                    [label] => 
                    [compound] => 
                    [tax_total] => 0
                    [shipping_tax_total] => 0
                    [rate_percent] => 
                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 11244
                    [name] => 
                    [rate_code] => DE-MWST.-1
                    [rate_id] => 1
                    [label] => MwSt.
                    [compound] => 1
                    [tax_total] => 7.54
                    [shipping_tax_total] => 0
                    [rate_percent] => 16
                )

            [cache_group:protected] => order-items
            [meta_type:protected] => order_item
            [object_type:protected] => order_item
            [id:protected] => 4543
            [changes:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [object_read:protected] => 1
            [default_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 0
                    [name] => 
                    [rate_code] => 
                    [rate_id] => 0
                    [label] => 
                    [compound] => 
                    [tax_total] => 0
                    [shipping_tax_total] => 0
                    [rate_percent] => 
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it this way may be after this code line

```
$custom_data = array(
    'custom_order_date_created'     => $custom_order_date_created,
)
```

Then the foreach loop with tax rate items and using [`WC_Tax` method `get_rate_percent()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.1/includes/class-wc-tax.php#L671-L681) to get the tax rate percentage as follows:

```
// Loop through order tax items
foreach ( $order->get_tax_totals() as $rate_code => $tax ) {

    // Store it in the array
    $custom_data['taxes'][] = array(
        'tax_rate'   =>  WC_Tax::get_rate_percent($tax->rate_id), // <=== the tax rate percentage
        'tax_amount' => $tax->formatted_amount
    );
}
```

Related:

- [How to get order tax details and rates in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281434/how-to-get-order-tax-details-and-rates-in-woocommerce/62286570#62286570)
- [Get separate Order's tax totals amounts with tax class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957544/get-separate-orders-tax-totals-amounts-with-tax-class/52958085#52958085)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to use your code in my function but I guess I need the data somehow in the `$custom_data` array. I'm extending a WooCommerce plugin with this code example: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/ordercustomer-csv-export-developer-documentation/#section-6

Comment: My answer here just answers in your initial question how to get the tax rate percentage and related amounts... I don't use woocommerce default export feature… $order->get_tax_totals() gives an array of `WC_Order_Item_Tax` objects just as `$order->get_items('tax')`…

Comment: I see, is there maybe an option to merge your array `$custom_data['taxes'][]` with the `$custom_data` array?

Comment: @Cray I don't know about WC export feature array needs for that.